# Java stream grouping by with custom value

Tags: java, java-stream, grouping

I have a `List<Person>`. With Java streams I can group the persons by last name using something like this:

```java
Map<String, List<Person>> persons.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getLastName));
```

But what if I want to group the *first name* of the persons by the last names? In other words, grouped by last name "Smith" I might have a list of "Jane" and "John". Is there maybe a value extractor version of `groupingBy()` I can use? I'm thinking something like this:

```java
Map<String, List<String>> persons.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getLastName, Person::getFirstName));
```

Comment: Apart from the answer given, you may use a simple for-loop. Unless this is homework, you don’t _have to_ use the Stream API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try use [`Collectors.mapping()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#mapping-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) as a downstream collector within the [`Collectors.groupingBy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) method:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;


class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Person> persons = List.of(
            new Person("Smith", "John"),
            new Person("Doe", "Jane"),
            new Person("Smith", "Alex"),
            new Person("Doe", "John"),
            new Person("Brown", "Charlie")
        );
        Map<String, List<String>> groupedByLastName = persons.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                Person::getLastName,
                Collectors.mapping(Person::getFirstName, Collectors.toList())
            ));
        System.out.println(groupedByLastName);
    }
}

class Person {
    private String lastName;
    private String firstName;

    public Person(String lastName, String firstName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person{lastName='" + lastName + "', firstName='" + firstName + "'}";
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
{Brown=[Charlie], Smith=[John, Alex], Doe=[Jane, John]}
```

Comment: Oh, OK. I missed that, because the method takes an additional collector (e.g. `toList()`) I hadn't expected. I see how it works, now. The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#mapping(java.util.function.Function,java.util.stream.Collector)) even has an example that's almost the same as mine.  Thanks.

Comment: Docs don't lie :)